# stuck in recursion of clojure - missing a bracket

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am writing a clojure recursion function so that given:

```
(luty [1 2 3 4])
```

should have output like this:

```
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ()
```

My code is:

```
(defn luty [a1]
 (if (empty? a1)
   (list )
     (cons (seq a1)  (luty (rest a1) )
  )))
```

I am getting output:

```
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4)) //comment missing a ()
```

Can anybody suggest me where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we print out the process and look at the second to last opperation:

```
user> (defn luty [a1]
        (println "a1 is" a1)
         (if (empty? a1)
             ()
           (cons (seq a1) (luty (rest a1)))))
#'user/luty
user> (luty [1 2 3 4])
a1 is [1 2 3 4]
a1 is (2 3 4)
a1 is (3 4)
a1 is (4)
a1 is ()
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4))
user> (cons '(4) ())
((4))
```

We can see that the result of adding `(4)` to the empty list is `((4))` rather than `((4) ())` as you would most likely want. This can be fixed by making the base case a list containing the empty list, instead of just an empty list

```
user> (defn luty [a1]
         (if (empty? a1)
           '(())
           (cons (seq a1) (luty (rest a1)))))
#'user/luty
user> (luty [1 2 3 4])
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ())
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of cons is a list with as the first element the first argument and *the rest of the list* as the second argument. If the second argument is empty or nil, that means you get a list with the first argument as the single member.

The reason for this is that lists are (conceptually, at least, in clojure) linked lists with 2-space cells; one pointer for the head element and one pointer for the tail (another list, which in clojure is guaranteed to be a seq-like thing - in many other lisps you can set the second pointer to any value you want, so you're not guaranteed to get a "proper" list out of a cons there). A nil in the "tail" position marks the end of the list.

Lists are the most easily implemented and understandable persistent (in the clojure sense of immutable, structure-sharing) data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a different way of looking at it:

```
user> (defn luty [a1]
        (reductions (fn [c _] (rest c)) (or (seq a1) '()) (-> a1 count range)))
   => #'user/luty
user> (luty [1 2 3 4])
   => ((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (3 4) (4) ())
user> (luty [])
   => (())
user> (luty nil)
   => (())
```